# Generics in Objects

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have a question about sealed class, generics and object.

Let's say I would like to model something like 3 finite cases with a sealed class something like this:

```kotlin
sealed class ChangeState<S> {
   fun reduceState(state: S): S
}

data class SetState<S>(val newState: S) : ChangeState<S>() {
    override fun reduce(state: S): S = newState
}

object NoStateChange : ChangeState<Nothing>() {  // What do I specify here for ChangeState? Nothing?

    override fun reduce(state: Nothing): Nothing {
        throw Exception("This should never be called")
    }
}
```

The goal is to provide a convenient way to define `NoStateChange` in a generic way that it can be used as following:

```kotlin
fun foo(i : Int) : ChangeState<Int> {
   return if (i==0)
            NoStateChange  // Won't compile because return type is ChangeState<Nothing> but expected ChangeState<Int>
          else 
            SetState(i)

}
```

Is there a way to do that with `object` and Generics somehow?

Comment: This would work if the return type of `foo` were `ChangeState<out Int>`. But then `reduceState` won't be callable on the return value. No way around that if the function can return something other than a usable `SetState<Int>`.

Comment: Why not `null` instead of `NoStateChange`? `fun foo(i : Int) : ChangeState<Int>? = if (i==0) null else SetState(i)`?

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks. I think I can refactor some pieces to get `reduceState()` function out of the class and then I think it should work with `<out Int>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Tenfour04 the issue is that `out` is needed but `reduceState()` would require `in` as well. However, `reduceState()` can be refactored out of the class hierarchy and moved to an extension function like that:

```kotlin
sealed class ChangeState<out S>

data class SetState<S>(val newState: S) : ChangeState<S>() 

object NoStateChange : ChangeState<Nothing>()



fun <S> ChangeState<S>.reduce(state: S): S {
    return when (val change = this) {
        is SetState -> change.newState
        is NoStateChange -> state 
    }
}
```